# Top n entries of a dictionary in python

Tags: python

Hi guys i have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
[[['Test', 0,1],['Test2', 0,4],['Test3', 0,5],['Test4', 0,2],['Test5', 0,6],...]]
```

How can I get the top two (for example)?

Expected result:

```
[['Test3', 0,5],['Test5',0,6]]
```

Comment: 1. This is not a dictionary. 2. "top" in what sense?

Comment: by the values (0,5, 0,4 etc). Is it a list then right?

Comment: @SiMon And what's the second value, `0`?

Comment: If you want to keep it a list, `lst.sorted(reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[2])[0:1]` might be a good start. See also https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 2):

```
test = [[['Test', 0,1],['Test2', 0,4],['Test3', 0,5],['Test4', 0,2],['Test5', 0,6]]]
result = sorted(test[0], key=lambda x: x[2])[-2:]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Test3', 0, 5], ['Test5', 0, 6]]
```

Something like this?

(I am assuming that you actually mean `['Test', 0, 1]` to be a list with 3 elements which is to be sorted by the third element rather than a two element list with the second element being a float, in which case it should be `['Test', 0.1]` and you can look at @jonrsharpe's answer. I also assumed that the output order (lowest to highest) is relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

Sort by the third value:

```
>>> sorted(l[0], key=lambda x: x[2])[-2:]
[['Test3', 0, 5], ['Test5', 0, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is *not* a dictionary, it is a list (`[]`) containing another list which contains lists. Each sub-sub-list contains three elements:

```
['Test2', 0, 4]
#^0       ^1 ^2
```

Note that Python doesn't allow the user of commas as decimal points; I think you want `0.4`.

Assuming that, sorting the sub-list and extracting the two highest sub-sub-lists is easy:

```
from operator import itemgetter
output = sorted(lst[0], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:2]
```

If I am wrong about the comma, make the argument to `itemgetter` `2`.